Python Pandas Dataframe Row name Change
How can I replace the first index 0 with "Color" and 1 with "Size"?
import pandas as pd
clothes = {"shirt": ["red", "M"], "sweater": ["yellow", "L"], "jacket": ["black", "L"]}

# pd.DataFrame.from_dict(clothes)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(clothes)
df

I tried like this but nothing changes. The output shows index name as an error
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(clothes, index = ['color', 'size'])


kindly share the expected output dataframe

https://ibb.co/F7mg2Gd
instead of 0 and 1 index it should be "color" and "size".

share data, not pic

df.set_index([['color','size']])?

{"shirt": ["red", "M"], "sweater": ["yellow", "L"], "jacket": ["black", "L"]}
is this you are talking about, i already add it in my post?

Nothing changes even no error is shown, same output with 0 and 1 index

assign back df = df.set_index([['color','size']]).

Solved. Thanks.

don't use from_dict, but the DataFrame constructor directly:
df = pd.DataFrame(clothes, index=['color', 'size'])

If the DataFrame is already existing, set_axis:
df = pd.DataFrame(clothes)

df = df.set_axis(['color', 'size'])

output:
      shirt sweater jacket
color   red  yellow  black
size      M       L      L


It is solved. Can you provide insights about when I should use (from_dict).

It is useful when the input dictionary has a different format than the one you have ({'col_name': ['col', 'values']}). You can check the documentation for examples.
